# Firefox 100% height, nobreak

Tags: css, templates, firefox, height, line-breaks

I want to build a template with two columns with 100% height.
They should stick together as one column, together about 960px.

Somehow, Firefox does its own thing and i just cant get the two columns 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/BbC4N/5/

```
<div id="head">Menu</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <div id="left" class="inner">LEFT</div>
        <div id="right" class="inner">RIGHT</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd recommend using `CSS` tables:

Here's a very simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BbC4N/9/

Comment: thank you. i made it now with `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`.

Comment: at all?, i only have IE8, i have to find a pc with IE7

Comment: You can use the browser mode of IE. Just open IE and hit `F12`. There are 2 buttons there: Browser mode and Document mode. Select IE7 for both. BTW why bother developing for IE7? Is that 1% of users so important to you?

Comment: i just checked IE7 in devMode and everything works. thank you. For me IE7 is not important. after i made the layout i will have to check for screen readers and so on but not for old IEs. :-) Thats what i hate about html and so on... i have to check hundreds of browsers...

Comment: True but a necessary evil... :(

Answer (score 1):

you could try using jquery:

```
var leftHeight = $('#left').height();
var rightHeight = $('#right').height();
if (leftHeight >= rightHeight) {
   $('#right').css({'height':leftHeight});
} else {
   $('#left').css({'height':rightHeight});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
.wrapper {
   display: table;
}
```

to:

```
.wrapper {
   display: block;
}
```

I've added to `.wrapper { margin-top: 48px; }` to make the `left` and `right` div's visible and everything seems to work for me in Firefox.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbC4N/8/)**